# Div not displaying to 'none' when creating window.AddEventListener

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an overlay in which I am looking to display to 'none' once all the content has been loaded in the page (basically creating a preloader).

I cannot see anything wrong with my code and therefore I am unsure as to why it is not working??

Any help would be great :-)

```
var overlay = document.getElementById("overlay");

window.addEventListener('load', function() {
overlay.style.display = 'none';
});


<div id="overlay">
  <div id="preloadSpinner">
    <img class="spin" src="image">
  </div>
</div>
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/67_DXhS3_Hc" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>


#overlay {
   height: 100%;
   Width: 100%;
   background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
   position: fixed;
   left: 0;
   top: 0;
}

.spin {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  margin:-60px 0 0 -60px;
  -webkit-animation:spin 4s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation:spin 4s linear infinite;
  animation:spin 4s linear infinite;
  }

  @-moz-keyframes spin { 
    100% { -moz-transform: rotate(360deg); } 
  }
  @-webkit-keyframes spin { 
    100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); } 
  }
  @keyframes spin {
    100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); transform:rotate(360deg); }  
  }
```

js fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gxL7erwy/28/

Comment: Think about why you try to change the style in the window onload event and then whether you'd need to get the element on which to operate in the same event handler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well your fiddle is set to run on window.onload so you are binding to window.onload inside of window.onload

SO your code is basically

```
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  var overlay = document.getElementById("overlay");

  window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    overlay.style.display = 'none';
  });
});
```

Change JSFiddle to run the script in the body and it will work. (Click the gear icon in the JavaScript panel and adjust the dropdown)